# Conflict with amsmath, ntheorem, and showlabels

Tags: amsmath, ntheorem, showlabels

The code below does not produce the labels for either of the equations. (I mean the labels that should be shown by showlabels, not the equation numbers.) Removing either of the options to ntheorem results in the labels being shown correctly. The labels for the sections and the items in the enumerates are shown using the code below. Is there a way to make the three packages work correctly together?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[amsmath , thmmarks]{ntheorem}
    \usepackage{showlabels}

\begin{document}

\section{my section}
\label{my section}

\begin{equation}
    \label{my equation}
    2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{my item}
\end{enumerate}

\section{my second section}
\label{my second section}

\begin{equation}
    \label{my second equation}
    2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{my second item}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use `showkeys` instead of `showlabels` (a 20+ year rivalry, I win this round:-)

Comment: Confound you, Carlisle – I'll get you yet! (*twirls moustache*).  @Stirling can you confirm that [1.8b1](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/showlabels/showlabels-1.8b1.tar.gz) works OK with your actual code?

Comment: Stirling and @david-carlisle : version 1.8 is [now at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showlabels).  Thanks for the problem report!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because package bug since been fixed as noted in comments